# Opening Amazon EC2 instance to HTTP Requests

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an Amazon EC2 instance. Via SSH, I've pulled my git repository and started my node server. I can see it has started correctly. My node server is listening on port 8080.

I then went to Security Groups and added a HTTP rule. This would only allow me to use port 80. When I go to the .compute.amazonaws.com:8080, the request times out. Do I need to change the HTTP rule to port 8080. If so, how do i do this? Its not allowing me...

Comment: just add an inbound rule for tcp 8080.

Comment: What os is ec2 instance?

Comment: @simon-p-r Its Linux

Comment: What flavour of linux?

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden just tried that, still getting webpage not available

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden actually that did work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are editing the Security Group inbound rules, instead of choosing HTTP under the 'Type', choose 'Custom TCP Rule'.  You will notice that when you select HTTP, the Protocol is TCP.  Choosing 'Custom TCP Rule' also uses 'TCP' protocol, but then it will allow you to change the port.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom TCP / 8080 rule to your SG.

[image]